# Вызывает ли себя анонимная функция в этом случае?

Tags: javascript, функции, анонимная-функция

Есть такой код:

```js
let obj, method;

obj = {
  go: function() { alert(this); }
};

(method = obj.go) ();   //  undefined
```

Что произойдет в этом куске кода: `(method = obj.go) ();`?

В первых скобках будет: `method = function() { alert(this); }`

После присвоения выражение в скобках будет таким: `function() { alert(this) ()`

Тут получается анонимная функция, вызывает себя или какая тут логика?

Comment: "анонимная функция вызывает себя" --- да.... IIFE (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Answer (score 0):

Если отвечать на вопрос, то нет, это не анонимная функция выполняющая себя, если бы это была анонимная функция тогда это выглядело бы так:

```js
(function() {
  method = obj.go()
})()
```

В вашем же случае сначала переменная `method` приравнивается к функции `go` и сразу после этого вызывается.

Comment: Объясните что получается в этом выражении `(method = obj.go)` !

Comment: @сергейпушкаев так в самом конце ответа у меня написано, что происходит в последней строке.

Comment: конечное выражение будет таким получается? `function() { alert(this)} ()`

Comment: Просто странно выглядит

Comment: @сергейпушкаев ну по сути нет, вот это выражение: `function() { alert(this)} ()`, будет возвращать строку с глобальным объектом (`[object Window]`), а если говорить про переменную которая является функцией (`method`), то тогда будет просто обычный объект (`[object Object]`).